# what would be the connection string for below in web.config?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I have written something like this but i am getting error as invalid username.
any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CS" connectionString="Data Source=DELL-PC;Initial Catalog=ASP; uid=DELL-PC\xxx;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Make sure the ASP.Net application pool account has rights to connect.

Comment: Have you tried SQL Server Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set Connection String in the Web Config file and just reference it based on your requirements.. see below

Web Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="SQLDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=<SERVER NAME>;Initial Catalog=<DATABASE NAME>;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then to get reference with the connections:

```
public string SQLServerDBConnstring()
{       
    return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDBConnectionString"].ToString();        
}
```